# Python Flask "return" is not applying css style

Tags: python, css, flask, return

I'm new in python / flask, so I'm probably not solving the issue the way it should be solved... Considering this, the question is:

I have a flask def(), which gets a POST from an HTML, and returns the text "File successfully processed".

What I want is for the "File successfully processed" to have the style in my styles.css file.

PS.: I already have an index.html which works great with the styles.css. The code in index.html is:

```
  <head>
  <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='css/styles.css') }}">
  </head>
```

So, how do I apply this styles.css to the return "File successfully processed"?

```
@app.route("/run_ctb", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def web_run_ctb():
if request.method == "POST":
    return "<p>File successfully processed<p>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That styles sheet is currently only applying to your index.html template. You should create a template for your "/run_ctb" page, for example called *run_ctb.html* which would look like:

```
<head>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ 
    url_for('static',filename='css/styles.css') }}">
</head>

<body>
    <p>File successfully processed<p>
</body>
```

Then you can just have your route function render the template:

```
    @app.route("/run_ctb", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def web_run_ctb():
        if request.method == "POST":
            return render_template('run_ctb.html')
```

Comment: Actually "File successfully processed" is one of dozen different returns I will provide. I just used this as example, but the return is dynamic. So I really need to apply the style in the return.

Comment: In that case, you can pass 'request.method' as an argument to the render_template function. Then in whichever template you're using, you can essentially embed that 'if' logic as described here:

https://overiq.com/flask-101/basics-of-jinja-template-language/#if-statement